# 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The 'To' number + is not a valid phone number

Tags: sms, twilio

This error comes up whenever I would have to append a plus symbol before a number. But if I manually add a number "+x xxx-xxx-xxxx" as string, it does work.

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The 'To' number + is not a valid phone number.**

I have this function:

```
function sendSMS($to,$msg){
    $from="+US_NUMBER_HERE";
    $AccountSid = ACCOUNT_ID;
    $AuthToken = ACCOUNT_TOKEN;
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    $to='+'.$to;
    $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage($from,$to,$msg);
}
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here. You seem to be passing the "+" symbol twice on your code. once when you pass the number in, and then when you concatenate it with the $to number.

Try making sure the $to only ever has one "+" in it, otherwise it will become an invalid number.

I would suggest adding the following on the 4th line of your function to make sure the number is correct:

```
print $to;
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for replying. Yes,  when I print out the to variable, I would get only the numbers without the +. The weird part is, the message gets sent to my phone and this error comes up. Still haven't found out why this happens :)

Comment: Am I going to try catch this one and maybe just ignore it? Messages do come in anyway :)

Comment: Are you sure this function is only being called once before the error happens? Maybe worth posting more of your code here.